# Web Hosting Panel Architecture

Tags: api, architecture

I'm currently working on custom hosting panel (Angular), which should interact with third party services like Proxmox, Billmanager, Zabbix, Grafana etc.

So my question is how this panel should interact with this services? Should I call directly each  of them by API? Or I need to integrate some kind of middleware API (laravel/django) and allow my angular panel to interact only with that API, and after each call this middleware API will call some of third party services (Proxmox, Zabbix etc) if needed?

I will add some schema of possible solutions.

Will be great if you can share some best practice examples.

Thanks in advance for your help)

[image: Possible solutions]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So based on some research v1 is a right choice.
This "middleware" is called API Gateway. And in such systems which includes interaction with lots of third party services we definitely need it.
Benefits

1. We can make all services private (no pubic access)
2. This adds async to all system
   etc